# .NET Maui - You are using a preview version of .NET - Where is this coming from and what version am I using?

Tags: maui

I am running VS 17.3 Preview 6 on windows11.  I have a .net maui app.  when i load the app into vs, I get a message saying that I am using a preview version of .net.  I don't think I've  installed a preview of .net6 on this machine since it is pretty much brand new.  i am using

- .net 6.0 - ios for ios.
- .net 6.0 - android for android.
- .net 6.0 - windows 10.0.10941.0 for windows, but don't plan to build for windows.

Basically, why am i getting a message about using a preview version of .net?  Is this some artifact message because I am using VS17.3 preview x?  any idea how to make this go away since it is annoying?  Is this due to .net 7 preview being installed with vs17.3?

Comment: You should be able to tell what version of .NET your maui app is using. Also is Maui out of preview? If so, that is news to me.

Comment: [GUESS]: It might be referring to a preview version of the .NET **SDK**. I think .Maui relies on a non-released version of some SDK functionality. (Perhaps the App Builder/Config/DI stuff.) `Tools / Command Line / Developer Command Prompt`, type `dotnet --info`: under ".NET SDKs installed:" the last one I see listed is `6.0.400-preview.22301.10`. That's what I'm guessing is being referred to. (That message would be a LOT more useful / less concerning, if it said exactly what version it was referring to, and whether it means "runtime" or "sdk"!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what version of MAUI you are using

1. Open solution or project in Visual Studio (Currently you should use Visual Studio Preview)
2. Right click on Project
3. Select `Manage NuGet Packages...`
4. Go to the register `Installed`
5. Check the versions of the packages `Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies` and `Microsoft.Maui.Extensions`

To find out what version of dotnet SDK you are using

1. Open PowerShell or cmd
2. Change directory to the path of your project
3. Execute `dotnet --version`

Comment: it appears that the VS17.3 preview6 installs .net 6.00.400.something preview.  Mystery solved.  I am guessing that we are still stuck with something in the chain stuck as preview until 17.3 actually ships.  Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I am running my app in the VS 17.3.0 release version and there are no messages about being in a preview version of .net core framework.